# How to convert numpy.timedelta64 to minutes

Tags: numpy, pandas, string-to-datetime

I have a date time column in a Pandas DataFrame and I'd like to convert it to minutes or seconds.

For example: I want to convert `00:27:00` to 27 mins.

```
example = data['duration'][0]
example
```

result: `numpy.timedelta64(1620000000000,'ns')`

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you mean `27 mins`, not `87 mins`? o_O

Comment: In the general case, do you want the fractional part, too?  E.g. if the input timedelta is `00:27:45`, do you want 27 or 27.75?

Comment: I'm more interested in minutes as my data doesn't include seconds, so no I don't need the fraction.

Comment: I figured you can get to the minutes by executing this line: mins = np.array([data['duration']], dtype = "timedelta64[m]")[0]. How can I append the values I receive in this array to my original data frame?

Comment: see docs here: very easy in 0.15 http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `array.astype()` to convert the type of an array safely:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.timedelta64(1620000000000,'ns')
>>> a.astype('timedelta64[m]')
numpy.timedelta64(27,'m')
```

Comment: Note that this will loose accuracy (based on the comments, this is ok for the questor, but should be highlighted for the general question): try `np.timedelta64(1621111111110,'ns').astype('timedelta64[m]')`

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @ntg, using `.astype('timedelta64[m]')` provides the result as an integer value, potentially reducing accuracy.

To obtain the result as a float value with full accuracy, we can scale the result to the desired units with `np.timedelta64(1, 'm')` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20739897/12131616).

---

Example:

```py
a = np.timedelta64(1621111111110,'ns')
print(a.astype('timedelta64[m]'))
print(a / np.timedelta64(1, 'm'))
```

Output:

```
27 minutes
27.0185185185
```